# Key down/up issue

Tags: c#

here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point lastClick;
        private Dictionary<Keys, bool> keyIsDown = new Dictionary<Keys, bool>();
        private Timer timer;
        private int stream1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.D1, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.D2, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.D3, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.D4, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.A, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.S, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.D, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.F, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.Z, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.X, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.C, false);
            keyIsDown.Add(Keys.V, false);

            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (true == keyIsDown.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode))
            {
                keyIsDown[e.KeyCode] = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (true == keyIsDown.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode))
            {
                keyIsDown[e.KeyCode] = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This makes the computer constantly call the playKeys method
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(playKeys);
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void playKeys(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (true == keyIsDown[Keys.D1])
            {
                Beat1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
            }
            else
            {
                Beat1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;

            }
            if (true == keyIsDown[Keys.D2])
            {
                Beat2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
            }
            else
            {
                Beat2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
            }

        }
```

And what happens is this:

```
Key D1 down = key D1 white.
Key D1 up = nothing happens until timer os over.
Key D2 down = Key D1 black.
Key D2 up = nothing happens until timer is over.
Key D1 down = Key D2 black...
etc...

Key D1 down + Key D2 down = Key D1 white + Key D2 white.
Key D1 up + Key D2 up = Key D1 and D2 stays the same until timer is over.

It should be:

Key D1 down = Key D1 white.
Key D1 up = Key D1 black.
Key D2 down = Key D2 white.
Key D2 up = Key D2 black.
```

(Even if both keys are down or up it shouldn't affect the behavior of the other key).

What it should happen when key is up should be immediately after the key is up, it only happens when its down.

How do i fix this?

Comment: The 10 second timer is very mysterious.  Just call playKeys() from your KeyUp and KeyDown methods.

Comment: @HansPassant uhm how? Do I call it within the Form_KeyUp/Down or where?

Comment: @HansPassant I think doing so he can't control the auto-repeating time (which should be 10 seconds).

Comment: @JoseCardama what do you mean by this `nothing happens until timer os over`? Looks like it does affect but too delay?

Comment: @KingKing Indeed the key should go back to the original state "black" after the key is up, but it delays.

Comment: @JoseCardama that's because the code changing your color back is not executed right at that time, it's executed **periodically** with interval of 10 seconds.

Comment: @KingKing And how do I fix this? could you please modify my code and show me if isn't that too much to ask? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JoseCardama as Hans Passant suggested, looks like you don't need any timer, I just thought you need some auto-repeating code run when the key is **held** down.

Comment: @KingKing What i don't want is when the key is down to be looped for ever, i'm going to play also a sound while the key is down and stop it when its up, but I don't want it to loop for ever.

Comment: @JoseCardama changing the `Interval` to `1` will quickly fix your issue, but you should consider using the code directly without any timer.

Comment: @KingKing The problem setting the interval to 1 is that if you add for example a dialog box, it will loop it and you'll get tons of dialog boxes on an unending loop until the key is no longer down, instead of just showing 1 dialog box when the key is down and removing it until the key is up.

Comment: @JoseCardama of course if you show some dialog, it can't be used but if it's just for changing backcolor seems to be ok, although as I said it's not recommended, using the code directly requires a `switch-case` which is very long indeed.

Comment: @KingKing Then what would you recommend to me if I indeed want to show some dialog or play a sound? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this incomplete code just to help you have some idea, you can add more `case` to fully implement your code:

```
bool keyDown;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(keyIsDown[e.KeyCode]) return;
    switch(e.KeyCode){
      case Keys.D1:
           Beat1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
           break;
      case Keys.D2:
           Beat2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.white_square_button;
           break;
    }
    keyIsDown[e.KeyCode] = true;
}
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{        
    switch(e.KeyCode){
      case Keys.D1:
           Beat1.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
           break;
      case Keys.D2:
           Beat2.Image = Beatpadpc.Properties.Resources.black_square_button;
           break;
    }
    keyIsDown[e.KeyCode] = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it actually worked except if I add sound it plays like the first ms of it then it loops.

Comment: @JoseCardama don't use any timer, you also don't need the `keyIsDown`, it can't loop the sound unless you **hold** down the key for a long time enough.

Comment: How to remove looping even if the key is held down for a long time?

Comment: @JoseCardama see my updated code, you can use 1 flag to control the behavior easily, I doubt there may be another option but using flag is a quick and easy solution for you.

Comment: The flag removes the looping but you can't now press both keys at the same time.

Comment: @JoseCardama looks like you have to keep the `keyIsDown` dictionary to use for your **very strange behavior**.

Comment: how do I do that? excuse my very poor knowledge. Thanks for helping me so far also!

Comment: @JoseCardama I also updated the code right after posting the previous comment, try it if it works for you now.